# Max Http concurrent connections per client

Tags: http, tomcat, web, concurrency

While I am reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser), I realize there is constraint in browser side to conform HTTP 1.1 RFC that is to limit concurrent connections to one domain. So I wonder, is there any similar constraint or limitation implemented in server side to conform this rule? For example, each IP only allowed specific number of Http concurrent connections established to the server.

I looked into Tomcat documentation, there is `maxConnection` and `maxThread` settings but none of them will actually enforce the rule up to IP level. If there is no such control in server side, does it mean there is a possibility that some clients could establish thousands of Http connections concurrently by using non-browser way (browser has limitation)? This is quite unsafe as some people will do this to attack the server. Can anyone clarify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Tomcat will allow thousands of connections from a single client. `maxConnections` and `maxThreads` do not care about the source of those connections.

You could implement a throttling `Valve` or `Filter` that would enforce QoS constraints, but no such component comes with Tomcat out of the box.